# How do i download files from a minio s3 bucket using curl

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, download, aws-cli, minio

I am trying to download contents of a folder from a minio s3 bucket.

i am using the following command.

I am able to download a specific file using

```
# aws --endpoint-url http://s3:9000 s3 cp s3://mlflow/3/050d4b07b6334997b214713201e41012/artifacts/model/requirements.txt .
```

But the below throws an error if it try to download all the contents of the folder

```
# aws --endpoint-url http://s3:9000 s3 cp s3://mlflow/3/050d4b07b6334997b214713201e41012/artifacts/model/* . 
fatal error: An error occurred (404) when calling the HeadObject operation: Key "3/050d4b07b6334997b214713201e41012/artifacts/model/*" does not exist
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Why don't you use aws cli or minio client to interact with s3?

Comment: updated the post with error i ran into using the AWS CLI. still getting an error.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script file that uses `cURL` and `openssl` to download a file from a MinIO server

Usage:

```bash
./download_minio.sh <HOST> <KEY> <SECRET> <BUCKET> <FILE ON MINIO> <OUTPUT PATH>
# Example: 
./download_minio.sh example.url.com mykey mysecret bucket-name minio/path/to/file.txt.zst /download/path/to/file.txt.zst
```

Script content `download_minio.sh` :

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Example: ./download_minio.sh example.url.com username password bucket-name minio/path/to/file.txt.zst /download/path/to/file.txt.zst

if [ -z $1 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a MINIO URL!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $2 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a USERNAME!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $3 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a PASSWORD!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $4 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a BUCKET!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $5 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a MINIO FILE PATH!"
  exit 1
fi

if [ -z $6 ]; then
  echo "You have NOT specified a DOWNLOAD PATH!"
  exit 1
fi


# User Minio Vars
URL=$1
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3
BUCKET=$4
MINIO_PATH="/${BUCKET}/$5"
OUT_FILE=$6

# Static Vars
DATE=$(date -R --utc)
CONTENT_TYPE='application/zstd'
SIG_STRING="GET\n\n${CONTENT_TYPE}\n${DATE}\n${MINIO_PATH}"
SIGNATURE=`echo -en ${SIG_STRING} | openssl sha1 -hmac ${PASSWORD} -binary | base64`
PROTOCOL="https"

curl -o "${OUT_FILE}" \
    -H "Host: $URL" \
    -H "Date: ${DATE}" \
    -H "Content-Type: ${CONTENT_TYPE}" \
    -H "Authorization: AWS ${USERNAME}:${SIGNATURE}" \
    ${PROTOCOL}://$URL${MINIO_PATH}
```

[Originaly created by JustinTimperio on Github](https://gist.github.com/JustinTimperio/ae695eef5fda1f1590a685a017bbb5ec)

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to get it by running

```
aws --endpoint-url http://s3:9000 s3 cp s3://mlflow/3/050d4b07b6334997b214713201e41012/artifacts/model . --recursive
```

The one problem i ran into was i had to use the aws-cli using pip install as that's the only way i could the --recursive option to work.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the `minio client` and set an alias on `minio` command. Here is an example taken from the  official [documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.html) showing how to achieve this using the docker version of `minio client`:

```
docker pull minio/mc:edge
docker run -it --entrypoint=/bin/sh minio/mc
mc alias set <ALIAS> <YOUR-S3-ENDPOINT> [YOUR-ACCESS-KEY] [YOUR-SECRET-KEY] [--api API-SIGNATURE]
```

You can instead install the client on any OS.

Once done, to copy content from s3 you would only have to do this:

```
{minio_alias} cp {minio_s3_source} {destination}
```